# s accessing mysql database on server from other PCs

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, phpmyadmin

I have installed XAMPP on a server PC.

I want to access it from other PC through MySQLWorkbench or even access it through server IP and PHPMyAdmin page.

I tried configuring the `httpd-xampp.conf` file but no use. I saw somewhere to edit MySQL file but don't know where to start editing.

What I want is that have a server with MySQL installed on it and 5-6 computers can access its database. We want to work in team, I don't want everyone to have different database copy and integrating everything in the end.

I already have installed VisualSVN on that server. But the MySQL issue is still remaining.

Can anyone guide me how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the xampp from the server. 
and Downloaded and Installed the MySQL Community Server Installer from the [mysql](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/) website

Everything it asks on installations, Assigned username and password during installation of mysql community server.
Everything worked like a charm.

Then connected the mysql work bench from other pc to the server using ip and port and password(which i provided to the mysql server during its installation on the server).

Now everything is working Great.. :)

Comment: The lesson being, I guess, while XAMPP is easy, sometimes it sucks ;p